# Get data returned by Google Pay API on backend

Tags: android, android-pay, google-pay

When performing a payment with Google Pay on my Android app, once the payment is validated, I get a `PaymentData` variable from which I can get some information, like email, shipping address, billing address, ...

Is there a way to get these information on my backend, without sending them in order to avoid alteration?

For instance, when I perform a Google Connect, with OAuth, I get a token which allows me to perform a request to Google's servers and retrieve by myself data like "mail", ... This way I can check if the mail was altered.

Thanks,

EDIT: here is the code from the Android application

```java
private void payWithGooglePay() {
    PaymentDataRequest.Builder request =
            PaymentDataRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setEmailRequired(true)
                    .setShippingAddressRequired(needShippingAddress)
                    .setTransactionInfo(
                            TransactionInfo.newBuilder()
                                    .setTotalPriceStatus(WalletConstants.TOTAL_PRICE_STATUS_FINAL)
                                    .setTotalPrice(String.valueOf(amountToPay / 100))
                                    .setCurrencyCode(currency.getCurrencyCode())
                                    .build())
                    .addAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_CARD)
                    .addAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKENIZED_CARD)
                    .setCardRequirements(
                            CardRequirements.newBuilder()
                                    .setBillingAddressRequired(needBillingAddress)
                                    .addAllowedCardNetworks(Arrays.asList(
                                            WalletConstants.CARD_NETWORK_VISA,
                                            WalletConstants.CARD_NETWORK_MASTERCARD))
                                    .build());

    PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters tokenizationParameters =
            PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder()
                    .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKENIZATION_TYPE_PAYMENT_GATEWAY)
                    .addParameter("gateway", "stripe")
                    .addParameter("stripe:publishableKey", liveMode ? getString(R.string.stripe_live_pk_key) : getString(R.string.stripe_test_pk_key))
                    .addParameter("stripe:version", "5.1.0")
                    .build();

    PaymentDataRequest paymentDataRequest = request
            .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(tokenizationParameters)
            .build();

    if (paymentDataRequest == null) {
        return;
    }

    AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest),
            getActivity(), ProgressViewActivity.PAYMENT_WITH_GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case ProgressViewActivity.PAYMENT_WITH_GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentData paymentData = PaymentData.getFromIntent(data);
                Log.d("MyGooglePay", "Google transaction ID: " + paymentData.getGoogleTransactionId());
                Log.d("MyGooglePay", "mail: " + paymentData.getEmail());
                Log.d("MyGooglePay", "token:" + paymentData.getPaymentMethodToken().getToken());
                Log.d("MyGooglePay", "extra: " + (paymentData.getExtraData() != null ? paymentData.getExtraData().toString() : ""));

                CardInfo cardInfo = paymentData.getCardInfo();
                String description = cardInfo.getCardDescription();
                Log.d("MyGooglePay", description);

                UserAddress shippingAddress = paymentData.getShippingAddress();
                UserAddress billingAddress = cardInfo.getBillingAddress();
                Log.d("MyGooglePay", "shipping: " + shippingAddress);
                Log.d("MyGooglePay", "billing: " + billingAddress);

                String rawToken = paymentData.getPaymentMethodToken().getToken();

                // Now that you have a Stripe token object, charge that by using the id
                Token stripeToken = Token.fromString(rawToken);
                if (stripeToken != null) {
                    // This chargeToken function is a call to your own server, which should then connect
                    // to Stripe's API to finish the charge.
                    Log.d("MyGooglePay", stripeToken.getCard().toJson().toString());
                    //sendFinalRequestAndGoToNext(stripeToken.getId());
                }
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

And just to be clear, what I want, is to get PaymentData *directly* from my backend instead of sending them from the app to my backend, to avoid alteration.

Comment: show us some code.

Comment: @olylo just edited the question

Comment: i have not tried google pay yet. i'm using google play billing library for my apps.

Answer (score 1):

this decoupled behavior from processors and gateways is intended, and it's there to maximize compatibility for all agents involved.

Sensitive information retrieved from Google Pay is encrypted such that only the processor of the payment can reveal the contents of the payload. Tampering with the content in the middle will simply render the payload invalid.

To be able to access that content, you can also opt to implement Google Pay using the [`DIRECT` integration](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography). Said so, note that payment processing involves complexity and compliance with regulatory terms like PCI DSS, and because of that, not recommended unless necessary otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my question. With Stripe, you can link some data to a source (like the mail address). But while with Google Pay the billing address is automatically set (so I can be sure that it was not tampered when I receive the request to my backend), the email is not.